# when i run my program it keeps throwing these errors

Tags: php, mysql

> **Warning:** Missing argument 1 for MysqlDB::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\index.php on line 9 and defined in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **10**
>
> **Warning:** Missing argument 2 for MysqlDB::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\index.php on line 9 and defined in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **10**
>
> **Warning:** Missing argument 3 for MysqlDB::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\index.php on line 9 and defined in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **10**
>
> **Warning:** Missing argument 4 for MysqlDB::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\index.php on line 9 and defined in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **10**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: host in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **11**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: username in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **11**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: password in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **11**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined variable: db in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ripplezsolution\phpinclude\include\MySqlDb.php** on line **11**

This is my MysqlDB.php code

```
    <?php

    class MysqlDB {

        protected $_mysql;
        protected $_where = array();
        protected $_query;
        protected $_paramTypeList;

        public function __construct ($host, $username, $password, $db) {
            $this->_mysql = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db)
                or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
        }
public function query($query) 
   {
      $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
      $stmt->execute();
      $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
      return $results;
   }

   /**
    * A convenient SELECT * function.
    *
    * @param string $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
    * @param int $numRows The number of rows total to return.
    * @return array Contains the returned rows from the select query.
    */
   public function get($tableName, $numRows = NULL) 
   {

      $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
      $stmt = $this->_buildQuery($numRows);
      $stmt->execute();

      $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
      return $results;
   }

   /**
    *
    * @param <string $tableName The name of the table.
    * @param array $insertData Data containing information for inserting into the DB.
    * @return boolean Boolean indicating whether the insert query was completed succesfully.
    */
   public function insert($tableName, $insertData) 
   {
      $this->_query = "INSERT into $tableName";
      $stmt = $this->_buildQuery(NULL, $insertData);
      $stmt->execute();

      if ($stmt->affected_rows)
         return true;
   }
   public function update($tableName, $tableData) 
   {
      $this->_query = "UPDATE $tableName SET ";

      $stmt = $this->_buildQuery(NULL, $tableData);
      $stmt->execute();

      if ($stmt->affected_rows)
         return true;
   }
   public function delete($tableName) {
      $this->_query = "DELETE FROM $tableName";

      $stmt = $this->_buildQuery();
      $stmt->execute();

      if ($stmt->affected_rows)
         return true;
   }
   public function where($whereProp, $whereValue) 
   {
      $this->_where[$whereProp] = $whereValue;
   }
   protected function _determineType($item) 
   {
      switch (gettype($item)) {
         case 'string':
            return 's';
            break;

         case 'integer':
            return 'i';
            break;

         case 'blob':
            return 'b';
            break;

         case 'double':
            return 'd';
            break;
      }
   }
   protected function _buildQuery($numRows = NULL, $tableData = false) 
   {
      $hasTableData = null;
      if (gettype($tableData) === 'array') {
         $hasTableData = true;
      }

      // Did the user call the "where" method?
      if (!empty($this->_where)) {
         $keys = array_keys($this->_where);
         $where_prop = $keys[0];
         $where_value = $this->_where[$where_prop];

         // if update data was passed, filter through
         // and create the SQL query, accordingly.
         if ($hasTableData) {
            $i = 1;
                $pos = strpos($this->_query, 'UPDATE');
                if ( $pos !== false) {
                    foreach ($tableData as $prop => $value) {
                        // determines what data type the item is, for binding purposes.
                        $this->_paramTypeList .= $this->_determineType($value);

                        // prepares the reset of the SQL query.
                        if ($i === count($tableData)) {
                            $this->_query .= $prop . " = ? WHERE " . $where_prop . "= " . $where_value;
                        } else {
                            $this->_query .= $prop . ' = ?, ';
                        }

                        $i++;
                    }
                }
         } else {
            $this->_paramTypeList = $this->_determineType($where_value);
            $this->_query .= " WHERE " . $where_prop . "= ?";
         }
      }
      if ($hasTableData) {
         $pos = strpos($this->_query, 'INSERT');

         if ($pos !== false) {
            $keys = array_keys($tableData);
            $values = array_values($tableData);
            $num = count($keys);
            foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
               $values[$key] = "'{$val}'";
               $this->_paramTypeList .= $this->_determineType($val);
            }

            $this->_query .= '(' . implode($keys, ', ') . ')';
            $this->_query .= ' VALUES(';
            while ($num !== 0) {
               ($num !== 1) ? $this->_query .= '?, ' : $this->_query .= '?)';
               $num--;
            }
         }
      }
      if (isset($numRows)) {
         $this->_query .= " LIMIT " . (int) $numRows;
      }
      $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();
      if ($hasTableData) {
         $args = array();
         $args[] = $this->_paramTypeList;
         foreach ($tableData as $prop => $val) {
            $args[] = &$tableData[$prop];
         }
         call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $args);
      } else {
         if ($this->_where)
            $stmt->bind_param($this->_paramTypeList, $where_value);
      }
      return $stmt;
   }
   protected function _dynamicBindResults($stmt) 
   {
      $parameters = array();
      $results = array();

      $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

      while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
         $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
      }
      call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $x = array();
         foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
         }
         $results[] = $x;
      }
      return $results;
   }
   protected function _prepareQuery() 
   {
      if (!$stmt = $this->_mysql->prepare($this->_query)) {
         trigger_error("Problem preparing query", E_USER_ERROR);
      }
      return $stmt;
   }
   public function __destruct() 
   {
        $this->_mysql->close();
   }
}
?>
```

and i'm calling a function insert() through index.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("phpinclude/include/membersite_config.php");
require_once("phpinclude/include/MySqlDB.php");
$DB = new MysqlDB('172.90.13.97','king','mi*****hhh','kxxxx_database');
if (isset($_GET['action'])){$action = htmlentities($_GET['action']);}
else{$action = NULL;}
$mysqldb = new MysqlDB();
?>
<?php if($action=='add_cart'){?>
<?php $data=array($arrival, $departure, $result, $roomID, $category_price); $table='tb_cart';?>
<?php $this->mysqldb->insert($table, $data); ?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Isn't the answer in the errors listed in your question? If that is your full code then the 4 vars host username password and db are null.

Comment: It's quite clear from the errors that you're not defining `$host`, `$password`, `$password`, or `$db`. This then causes the `MysqlDB::__construct()` to fail.

Comment: i used the values instead of $host, $password, $password, and $db. Still the error is there

Comment: You're probably instantiating the class without arguments, like `$conn = new MysqlDB()`... Post your code where you instantiate the object.

Comment: i'm new to stack overflow, so i don't know how to post the code in comment with the code format. should i just copy paste it??

Comment: @pankaj Post it in your question not it the comments. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @pankaj edit your question and insert the code there! The links are just below your post tags

Comment: @Rizier123 i have posted the code. i hope i've done it right this time.

Comment: @pankaj See that line: `$mysqldb = new MysqlDB();` ?

Comment: As I've suspected. Line 9, no arguments.

Comment: And I don't get why you're constructing two MysqlDB... Won't just one suffice (the `$DB` one)?

Comment: okay thanks all. i will edit and see if it works

Comment: thanks guys. u are the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
 $mysqldb = new MysqlDB();
```

The constructor requries arguments which are not passed. You need to pass $host, $username, $password, $db to constructor.

Your code acutally makes no sense. You could use `$DB` instead of creating new object. You also use `$this->mysqldb` in no object context. There are plenty of errors in your code.

To fix:

1. Remove this line `$mysqldb = new MysqlDB();`
2. Change `<?php $this->mysqldb->insert($table, $data); ?>` to `$DB->insert($table, $data);`

Script should +- look like:

```
 <?php

 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once("phpinclude/include/membersite_config.php");
 require_once("phpinclude/include/MySqlDB.php");
 $DB = new MysqlDB('172.90.13.97','king','mi*****hhh','kxxxx_database');

 $action = !empty($_GET['action']) ? htmlentities($_GET['action']) : null;

 if ($action == 'add_cart') {
      $data = array(
                      'arrival'        => $arrival,
                      'departure'      => $departure, 
                      'result'         => $result, 
                      'roomID'         => $roomID, 
                      'category_price' => $category_price
     );
     $DB->insert('tb_cart', $data);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. i was looking in all the wrong places for error.

Comment: Pay attention to formatting it really helps reading the code. You should look at PSR standards -> www.php-fig.org/psr/